# Can an opponent's wand be summoned in a duel?

Tags: harry-potter, spells

I know there are countless examples where a person summoned things that are not his (Hermione summoning the Horcrux books etc.). Also in Order of the Phoenix Ministry battle,

> “Accio Wand !” cried Hermione. Harry’s wand flew from a dark corner
>   into her hand and she threw it to him.

So someone else's wand can be summoned. So is there any magic that prohibits a summoning charm during a duel. What an amazing moment that would be if two persons are dueling and one's wand would be summoned out of his hands.

Comment: That wouldn't be a very exciting duel, though ;)

Comment: I think you would need a combination of Expelliarmus and Accio, that would surely work. (Then a booming voice would say, "COMBO!" and you would get loads of duel points). I don't think you could just slip it out of their hands though - I imagine their grip would be enough to counter it. Though I suppose Hermione was able to Summon books out of Dumbledore's office and they must have faced resistance on their way to her.

Comment: @ThruGog  You saying grip wins against Magic??

Comment: @prakharlondhe Funny enough, in some circles of Magic the Gathering players, a hand of cards is called a grip.

Comment: **Acciolliarmus!**

Comment: @prakhar londhe I think grip might win against "come here please" magic, yes. The Summoning Charm seems to be more about convenience than a combat spell.

Answer (score 7):

Most likely yes. As we see in *Order of the Phoenix*:

> The words were hardly out of his mouth when the female Death Eater shrieked, “Accio Proph —”
>   Harry was just ready for her. He shouted “Protego!” before she had finished her spell, and though the glass sphere slipped to the tips of his fingers he managed to cling on to it.

Here we have someone summoning an item out of another's hand, and Protego blocking the spell. As far as we know there is nothing that would stop a wand from being summoned, in fact Expelliarmus throws the wand away from the owner, so we know magic can separate a wand from a wizard or a witch.

Comment: Expelliarmus requires considerable strength, summoning charm doesn't require much strength. Also here Harry was expecting The charm, but most people won't expect accio in a duel, they wouldn't be ready with a protego... And I don't think protego would be useful against expelliarmus, its a powerful spell...

Comment: @prakharlondhe why exactly most people wouldn't expect accio in a duel? If this was allowed and possible, then it would be common to try, and if it would be common to try, people would expect it to be tried on them.

Comment: @Mołot Is there any canon that this is **not allowed** and **not possible**?

Comment: @prakharlondhe no, and that's why I'm inclined to think this doesn't happen because they guard against it instead. That was exactly my point.

Comment: @prakharlondhe actually if you remember summing is a far more advanced spell then disarming, harry and gain learned disarming in year 2 easily, it takes harry weeks to lesrn to summon properly in yesr 4

Comment: @Himarm only Harry did it in 2 because, well , it was one of his would-be- all -time-favorite spell... I am sure no one else **ordinary** could have managed that in his/her second year... it was just they needed to teach students defense....Well yes also you are right, Harry learnt summoning later, so it might be a more difficult spell...

Answer (score 2):

I'm just using logic to answer this question.
We see many times in the books wands can actually be targeted by movement spells, just like every other object with a physical manifestation.

This said, i think the logic behind the "Protego" works fine.
For example, during the duel between Dumbledore and Voldemort in the Ministry of Magic not a single word is spelled while the two of them keep shooting every sort of wizardry to each other, and countering the opponent moves as well.

I think it's correct to presume they are constantly countering that kind of attack too; considering the fact that losing the wand means sure death or at least demise in a duel, preventing this should be one of the first safety points to take care of.

If i can make an off-topic example to show a similar logic in another fictional universe, it is the following. What would prevent a Force user (SW universe) to shut the opponent's lightsaber off with the Force?
Clearly nothing, it's a physical object and thus subjected to Force manipulation. The canon answer is: both duelers are constantly keeping their weapon controlled and on with the Force.

In the same way, wizards must , or at least should, be constantly protecting the vessel of their power.

EDIT: i also came up with another theory. In the books we see certain kind of objects immune to the Accio spell (E.G. Horcruxes, Harry's Invisibility Cloak..)
We know they are powerful magic items, but they *must have been crafted by someone*.
This means, whoever imbued them with their respective abilities, has also given particular qualities, such as regeneration for Horcruxes and durability for the Invisibility spell on the coak.
Thus, what should stop a good mage to enchant his own wand not to be subjected to such a powerful threat? Think it once, make your magic, end. Easy done, given you have enough power to cast such a spell.

Comment: The Star Wars bit is absolutely off topic. Please try to stick to canon explanations.

Comment: Sorry, i specified it was off topic, it was only to provide a comparison of some sort